# Jquery Autocomplete faild with json response in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement jquery-ui autocomplete into a rails application. I have following model into my rails application.

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, through: :user_skills
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

And I am trying to applying to autocomplete on skill name. I have created the following action into my home controller.

```
def skills_autocomplete
  @skills = Skill.order(:name).map(&:name)
  render json: @skills
end
```

And I defined this action into routes as:

```
get 'skills_autocomplete' => "home#skills_autocomplete"
```

And Below is the snippet of jquery autocomplete:

```
$(function() {
    var availableSkills = 'skills_autocomplete.json';
    $('#skills').autocomplete({
      source: availableSkills
    });
  });
```

But with this implementation when type any letter into search box this will show all the skills into autocomplete box. On the other hand if I user following implementation :

```
$(function() {
    var availableSkills = [".NET","ASP.NET","AWS","Android","Angular 1","Angular 2+","Bitbucket","Block Chain","C","C#","C++","CSS3","DevOpps","Django","Docker","Express Js","GIT","GITLAB","GraphQL","HTML5","Heroku","IoT","Ionic","JSON","Java","Javascript","Jquery","Jquery UI","MEAN Stack","Material Design","Mongo DB","Node Js","PHP + MySQL","PHP Laravel","Postgresql","Python","React Native","Ruby","Ruby on Rails","Sinatra","Symentic UI","Twitter Bootstrap","Wordpress","XML"]
  $('#skills').autocomplete({
    source: availableSkills
  });
});
```

The autocomplete works fine. Can anyone please help what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking on lot of options I observed that array returned as JSON response not processed by autocomplete. So I did something like this and got autocomplete worked fine now.

```
$(function() {
  var skills = 'skills_autocomplete.json';
  availableSkills = [];
  $.getJSON(skills, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
      availableSkills.push(value);
    });
  });
  $('#skills').autocomplete({
    source: availableSkills
  });
});
```

Problem solved now.